# How to draw an outer border for a donut chart - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a donut chart as shown [below ]

http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/

I have a few requirements here:

1. I would like to draw an outer border for this donut. I noticed that specifying the border attribute draws an inner as well as outer border.
2. Can I display some text in the center of the donut? I wish to display the total number in this case. Any pointers here will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

for displaying the text, you can use, `chart.renderer.text()` as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/462/

hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response. This will work provided I know where exactly the center of the pie lies. In my case I am centering the pie at 40%,50% of my div using the 'center' option provided by Highcharts API. Is there a way to determine the exact center point?

Comment: updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/464. hope this will be the one you are looking for

Comment: I managed to render my text using the title attribute [link]http://jsfiddle.net/pDdcd/8/ . I want to an on click event for the title. Is this possible?

Comment: changing the div to href did the trick. I was able to fire an on click event

Comment: you can also try clcik event provided by highcharts also